# How to get the InnerHTML of dynamic loading webpage?

Tags: java, jaunt-api

I am new to java and using a jaunt1.3.8 library for web scraping.
I am trying to get the InnerHTML of the webpage : https://www.justdial.com/Pune/Cake-Shops/nct-10070075.

the site will not show us the full list of search results.
when we reach the bottom of the page it will load again.

it will stop loading after 10 scrolls.

I want to scrap the data of this dynamic loading webpage using the jaunt1.3.8 library but I don't know how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

This is your first page: https://www.justdial.com/Pune/Cake-Shops/nct-10070075/page-1

PagniaE = "https://www.justdial.com/Pune/Cake-Shops/nct-10070075/page-1";

Make a loop:

```
while (IniPag<=100) {
  userAgent.visit(PaginaE);
  // (do someting)...
  PaginaE = PaginaE.replace("page1","page2"); //Dynamic
}
```